# Adding a link to external website and it's synopsis in my HTML

Tags: javascript, html

In facebook, when I add a link to a website, it automatically brings some synopsis (text and images) from the external website and adds it to the page...

Something like this:

[image]

How can this be done? I simply don't know where to start and what to google to find a tutorial about this.

Comment: someone posted [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/) as answer, but later deleted it... I found the link useful though, which explains how facebook crawlers work.

Comment: That answer was actually deleted by a moderator. Can't say for certain why that might be, but I'd imagine it could be because the entirety of its usefulness was tied to an external resource.

Comment: The way facebook does this would be with a request to the link, then inspecting the returned html, looking and parsing meta tags etc. A good chunk of this would be done server side to handle CORS issues.

Comment: @TylerRoper, thanks a lot for both your answer and explanation. I thought it would be usefull to keep that link in the comments, in case someone else finds it useful in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for are *Open Graph Meta Tags*. By including these in the `<head>` of your page, Facebook can then use this information to generate useful previews.

> To turn your web pages into graph objects, you need to add basic metadata to your page. We've based the initial version of the protocol on RDFa which means that you'll place additional `<meta>` tags in the `<head>` of your web page. The four required properties for every page are:
>
> **og:title** - The title of your object as it should appear within the graph, e.g., "The Rock".
>
> **og:type** - The type of your object, e.g., "video.movie". Depending on the type you specify, other properties may also be required.
>
> **og:image** - An image URL which should represent your object within the graph.
>
> **og:url** - The canonical URL of your object that will be used as its permanent ID in the graph, e.g., "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/".
>
> As an example, the following is the Open Graph protocol markup for The Rock on IMDB:
>
> ```
> <html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
>   <head>
>     <title>The Rock (1996)</title>
>     <meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
>     <meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
>     <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
>     <meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
>     ...
>   </head>
>   ....
> </html>
> ```

The excerpt above, as well as additional properties and information, can be found here: [**The Open Graph protocol**](http://ogp.me/).